# How to style input field number up & down button on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to style the up and down button of the input field number on FF. I have successfully achieved this on chrome with the below code but I can't find any CSS trick to do it on FF.

I can't use JS to do this.

Is it possible to style the up and down using CSS in FF? if so how? - I only need to achieve this on the latest version

**DOM**

```
<div class="productQty">
    <span></span>
    <input type="number" max="10" min="1" class="mod"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="number"] {
    height: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
.productQty span {
    display: block;
    width: 41px;
    height: 30px;
    background: white;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: solid 1px #999999;

}

/* Spin Buttons modified */

input[type="number"].mod::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"].mod::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent url("../img/updown.png") no-repeat center center;
    width: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1; /* shows Spin Buttons per default (Chrome >= 39) */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
input[type="number"].mod::-moz-inner-spin-button:hover,
input[type="number"].mod::-moz-inner-spin-button:active{
    border: none;
}

/* Override browser form filling */
input:-webkit-autofill {
    background: black;
    color: red;
}
```

How does it look on chrome and how it **should** look

[image]

How does it looks in FF 38

[image]

Comment: can you please send the code using jsfiddle...please

Comment: those vendor prefixes may have something to do with it. Have you looked at the demos in the comments on https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/ ?

Comment: tbh you're best bet is to *make it yourself*. The browser support can be dodgy at the best of times, so I'd recommend making a custom one

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly apply css to the buttons on FF, there is a bugreport about it:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1108469

If you don't mind to apply some css to the containing element, you could use the `:before` and `:after` to overlay custom buttons.

```css
div:before, div:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
    height: 8px;
    line-height: 8px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    left: 136px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
}

div:before {
    content: "+";
    top: 11px;
}

div:after {
    content: "-";
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="number" /></div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The bug report doesn't say that much actually: Just that it doesn't work currently.

Comment: That comment just means you're answer has been flagged to be deleted. If another reviewer agrees and you don't make a change to the answer SO will remove the "answer"

Comment: Those "custom buttons" aren't functional though.

Comment: True; they are not functional, hence the 'pointer-events: none'. This way the "click" goes "through" the styled element to actually "click" on the functional buttons...